# A dictionary with a given key type cannot be assigned as a dictionary of objects

Tags: python, dictionary, type-hinting, mypy

It looks like a dictionary of `SomeKeyType` cannot be assigned as a dictionary of `objects`, even though all types are subtypes of `object`:

```py
x: dict[str, str] = {"a": "b"}
y: dict[object, str] = x
```

```
Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Dict[str, str]", variable has type "Dict[object, str]")
```

[Copying](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#invariance-vs-covariance) doesn't help either:

```py
x: dict[str, str] = {"a": "b"}
y: dict[object, str] = dict(x)
```

```
Argument 1 to "dict" has incompatible type "Dict[str, str]"; expected "SupportsKeysAndGetItem[object, str]"
```

A similar error occurs when updating a dictionary of `objects` with a dictionary of another type:

```py
x: dict[object, str] = {"a": "a"}
y: dict[str, str] = {"b": "b"}

x.update(y)
x = {**x, **y}
x |= y
```

```
Argument 1 to "update" of "dict" has incompatible type "Dict[str, str]"; expected "Mapping[object, str]"
Argument 1 to "update" of "dict" has incompatible type "Dict[str, str]"; expected "Mapping[object, str]"
Argument 1 to "__ior__" of "dict" has incompatible type "Dict[str, str]"; expected "Mapping[object, str]"
```

Note that a naive implementation of `dict.update` does **not** generate any typing issue:

```py
for k, v in y.items():
    x[k] = v
```

Is that on purpose or is it an issue I should report on the mypy tracker?

Comment: How about `y: dict[Any, str] = x`?

Comment: @AKX that will probably make the error go away, but now OP's keys are untyped, which likely isn't what they want

Answer (score 2):

While a `str` is an `object`, it's not generally true that an `F[str]` is an `F[object]` for some type constructor `F`. For example, a `dict[str, ...]` is apparently not a `dict[object, ...]`. This is likely because `dict[K, V]` is *invariant* in its key type `K`, whereas you'd need it to be *covariant*. Types are often invariant in a type parameter because the type appears in both method argument and return type positions, like `dict.__getitem__(key: K) -> V` and `dict.keys() -> KeysView[K]`.

You can fix your code by typing `x` as `dict[object, str]`. I guess this works because mypy then infers the `"a"` as an `object`, as opposed to inferring the `dict[str, str]` as a `dict[object, str]`. Whether that's the best solution for you depends on your context.

See [this section](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html?highlight=contravariance#variance-of-generic-types) of the mypy docs for more info on in-/co-/contravariance.

[This discussion](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/445) looks relevant though I only skimmed it.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the references! Still, the copy version should have worked, right? Same thing for the `update` method: it fails in the same way when updating a `dict[object, ...]` with a `dict[str, ...]`, even though the explicit loop-and-set-items approach works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Vincent the copy method may be typed to return exactly what is passed in, in which case there's no difference

Comment: @Vincent I'd have to see some code re update and loop-and-set to see what you mean

Comment: I updated my post to include some examples of conflicting types when updating a dictionary.

Comment: @Vincent I think the other forms that don't work probably fall into the same category as above. The loop works because you're adding bare `str`s and `object`s which do satisfy the subtyping relationship